# Gimp dpi changes upon saving work

Tags: gimp, dpi

After I installed the latest version of GIMP 2.10.14 it keeps changing the size of my work the moment I hit save.
To see what what happening I opened a white A4 page and the size was 8.267 x 11.693(inches), 2840 x 3508 pixels at 300dpi. When I hit save as .xcf it then changed size and became 34.444 x 48.722(inches), 2840 x 3508 pixels @ 72dpi.
This is seriously mucking up my work but I have no idea why it's doing it or how to fix it. Any ideas please???

Answer (score 1):

[Known bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/4194), fixed in 2.10.16. If it's a real bother and you can't way for 2.10.16, go back to 2.10.12 (bug is only in 2.10.14).

Note that this bug only changes the "print definition" metadata, there is no impact to the image pixels.